# Is "quantity" a proper word to use for "the number of things" in technical topics?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I am looking for a technical term for the *number of things*.

In my native Danish lanauge, we have one single word:

> Antal

which directly means *the number of*.

In English, the word *amount* wouldn't work, since it applies to things that cannot be counted, such as *an amount of water*. Instead I have so far been using the word:

> Quantity

This fits to what I can [look up](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/quantity) in [dictionaries](https://www.ordbogen.com/da/search#/auto/ordbogen-enda/quantity), at least in some of its meanings.

But the word *quantity* is also often used in other ways, for example in technical discussions to say

> A vector quantity
>   A scalar quantity

In this use, *quantity* means something like *proporty* or *value* (or something which can have a value), [which Wikipedia agrees with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity), and not *the number of* anything.

Sometimes I am thinking if I should use the word:

> Count

as in *the count* or *a count*, but it sounds a bit off since I can't use it properly in a sentence as: *a count of apples*.

What is the best possible term to use for *the number of*?

Comment: How about "the number of"?  If you need a single word, I think quantity is good.  Could you give some examples of how you want to use it?  Are there cases where you think "quantity" would be misleading?

Comment: @pfalstad I would like a single term, yes. The issue is that I want to use the word in technical contexts. As a property of things, in category with *time* and *space* (position), *temperature* and *mass*. The term *quantity* fits fine, but I am worried about its meaning as *property*.

Comment: In UK media English, much to my regret, **amount** has shouldered **number** aside and one comes constantly across **amounts of people, cars, animals** and the like. In short, number's days appear to be numbered in this respect.

Comment: *Water* is an uncountable *word*, true, but actual water is measurable. 'The quantity [of water] was 55.94 liters' is perfectly fine.

Comment: It would be easier if you give us an example sentence or two where you think quantity isn't working, and ask us to come up with a better way to put it.